# Audio automatically turns on once on website - Audio tags html

Tags: html

I have put a piece of code to play audio for my website like this

```
<audio id="audio-background" style="visibility: hidden;" controls autoplay>
  <source src="/mp3/background-music.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

However, when users regularly visit my website, it keeps repeating annoying them. I want when the customer comes in and the audio turns on only once.
Anyone with any experience can help me make it up! Thanks

Comment: Weird, you don't have the loop attribute so it should not loop

Comment: There are [various reasons](https://www.argondesign.com.au/digital/why-adding-background-music-on-your-site-is-a-bad-idea/) why playing background music is generally considered a bad idea (even if it's just at the first visit). You may want to reconsider adding background music, maybe you find a better way for your visitors to start the music themself if they want to.

Comment: You should track users by session. Then if it's new user - apply audio auto-play

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have a loop attribute I'm assuming your users are hearing this everytime the page reloads, and perhaps at every site navigation.

If you included this tag in your main view, and the view refreshes when the user navigates to a child route (if you use php for routing for example, like wordpress does) it would reload the page and trigger the audio every time.

If this is the case, you may want to use localStorage ([more on that here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)) to keep a record the user has visited the page and not include this audio tag for those who have already visited the site.

You can do that by doing something like this in javascript

```
window.localStorage.setItem('notFirstVisit', true);
```

and checking on page load:

```
let notFirstVisit = window.localStorage.getItem('notFirstVisit');
```

and then adding or removing the audio tag using javascript

```
if(notFirstVisit){
  let audioElement = document.getElementById(audioElementId);
  audioElement.remove();
}
```

Other options include keeping a php session and using php to include the audio tag or not, or using cookies.